# SQL Server 2008 Pivot without Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, aggregation

I am facing a problem trying to perform a pivot on the table. A sample of what I want is as shown below.

```
ProductBarcode    ProductID
--------------    ---------
1000              P1
1001              P1
1002              P2
1003              P3
1004              P4
1005              P4
```

Now I want to transform the above table into something as below.

```
ProductID    Barcode1    Barcode2
---------    --------    --------
P1           1000        1001
P2           1002        
P3           1003        
P4           1004        1005
```

I was trying to work it out with the following query but it wasn't giving the required results:

```
SELECT 
  [r1].[productID],
  [r1].[Productbarcode] as Barcode1,
  [r2].[ProductBarcode] as Barcode2
FROM products as r1 right JOIN products as r2 on r1.[productID] = r2.[productID]
```

Now this is just an example and in actual case, there are hundreds of products which have multiple barcodes.

I have even tried using the following query but all I got was a null in both the barcode columns.

```
SELECT productID,[barcode1],[barcode2]
FROM
(SELECT barcode, productID
FROM products) as TableToBePivoted
PIVOT
(MAX(barcode)
FOR barcode IN ([barcode1], [barcode2])
) AS PivotedTable;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to PIVOT without aggregating.

But here is how to get what you want, enter however many columns (barcodes) you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1(
    ProductBarcode VARCHAR(10),
    ProductID  VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO #table1(ProductBarcode, ProductID)
VALUES
('1000' ,'P1'),
('1001' ,'P1'),
('1002' ,'P2'),
('1003' ,'P3'),
('1004' ,'P4'),
('1005' ,'P4');


WITH T AS(
    SELECT 'Barcode' + RTRIM(LTRIM(STR( ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY  ProductBarcode)))) AS BarcodeNum,
           ProductBarcode, 
           ProductID    
           FROM #table1
) 
SELECT * FROM T
PIVOT(MAX(ProductBarcode) FOR BarcodeNum IN([Barcode1], [Barcode2])) P
```

Results:

```
ProductID  Barcode1   Barcode2
---------- ---------- ----------
P1         1000       1001
P2         1002       NULL
P3         1003       NULL
P4         1004       1005
```

Comment: Thanks for that Cooper. I tried the query you have written and I do get the barcodes under Barcode1 column but under Barcode2 column, it shows all NULL.

Comment: @Misbah - I'm using your sample data, worked for me fine. Do you get the exepected results when querying everything except for the line with the pivot operator?

Comment: @Misbah Yanus - I posted all sql used to create your sample data and query that will produce expected results

Comment: I just tried creating from scratch and doing the above query again and it worked. Might have been my fault while running it for the first time. Thanks a lot!!
Cheers